# El rellenar un listbox con datos de una clase, me aparece el nombre de la clase

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo un problema, Necesito llenar un Listbox con los datos de los trabajadores que debe ingresar el usuario. El problema es que no puedo rellenar una listbox que muestre los datos de los trabajadores.

```
public class CLista2
    {

        public static List<CPlanilla> ListaPlanillas { get; set; }

        public CLista2() {

            if (ListaPlanillas == null) { ListaPlanillas = new List<CPlanilla>(); }

        }

        public void RegistrarPlanilla(CPlanilla planilla) {

            ListaPlanillas.Add(planilla);

        }


        public bool PlanillaExiste(string dni) {

            return ListaPlanillas.Exists(p => p.DNI == dni);
        }

    }
```

Form para registrar un trabajador:

```
if (txtbxDNI.Text != "" && txtbxRUC.Text != "" && txtbxNombre.Text != "" && txtbxSueldo.Text != "" && txtbxFechaDePago.Text != "" && txtbxDescueto.Text != "")
                if (!objLista2.PlanillaExiste(txtbxDNI.Text)) {

                    CPlanilla planilla = new CPlanilla();
                    planilla.DNI = txtbxDNI.Text;
                    planilla.RUC = txtbxRUC.Text;
                    planilla.NombreDelPersonal = txtbxNombre.Text;
                    planilla.SueldoPorAbonar = double.Parse(txtbxSueldo.Text);
                    planilla.FechaDePago = txtbxFechaDePago.Text;
                    planilla.descuento = double.Parse(txtbxDescueto.Text);
                    objLista2.RegistrarPlanilla(planilla);
```

Aqui es donde intento rellenar la lista pero en vez de que me aparezcan todos los datos pero solo me devuelve "SoftwareContabilidad.CPlanilla"

```
 private void FrmConsultarPlanillas_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listbxPlanilla.DisplayMember = "NombreDelPersonal" + "DNI"+"RUC";
            listbxPlanilla.ValueMember = "DNI";
            listbxPlanilla.DataSource = CLista2.ListaPlanillas;
            listbxPlanilla.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
```

Cualquier  tipo de ayuda es bienvenida. Gracias de antemano

Comment: sobre escribe el método toString() de tu clase CPlanilla con los 3 datos que deseas mostrar "NombreDelPersonal" + "DNI"+"RUC";

Comment: Esa es la respuesta @jtaborga. Podes ponerla como respuesta y agregar un poquito de contexto de porque pasa lo que le pasa?

Comment: Claro que si. La colocaré como respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La razón del por qué se sobre escribe el método `ToString()`, es para tener una representación por defecto del objeto como cadena `String`, normalmente se usa para mostrar al usuario alguna información en la UI, en los logs o en las consolas, Así:

```
Console.WriteLine(tuClaseObjeto);
```

Si no sobre escribes el método `ToString()`, entonces la implementación del objeto por defecto es retornar el `fully qualified name` o `Nombre Completo de tu clase`, Así:

```
TuNamespace.TuNombreDeClase
```

Ahora bien, cambiando esta implementación heredada de la clase (`System.Object`), Entonces puedes realizar una mejor representación de tu objeto, para facilitar su lectura que se conoce como (Pretty Reading, o Pretty Print), Así:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("Esta instancia de Objeto tiene las siguientes propiedades: Nombre = {0}, Numero= {1}, Fecha = {2}, Salario = ${3}", _nombre, _numero, _fecha, _salario);
}
```

Ahora bien, cuando enlazas el ListBox a una colección de objetos:
Lo que espera el ListBox en el DisplayMember es una cadena con una sola Propiedad de tu clase podría ser DNI o NombreDelPersonal y en caso de que no encuentre la Propiedad, busca la implementación por defecto del objeto, que sería el método `ToString()`.

```
        private void FrmConsultarPlanillas_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listbxPlanilla.DisplayMember = "NombreDelPersonal" + "DNI"+"RUC";
            listbxPlanilla.ValueMember = "DNI"; 
            //enlace a lista de objetos
            listbxPlanilla.DataSource = CLista2.ListaPlanillas;
            listbxPlanilla.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
```

Espero que sea de tu Ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: Agregando el método ToString en mi clase CPlantilla funcionó. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo tienes debido a que DisplayMember requiere una cadena que especifique la propiedad del objeto que deseas mostrar.

```
listbxPlanilla.DisplayMember = "NombreDelPersonal" + "DNI"+"RUC"; // Es incorrecto pues la propiedad "NombreDelPersonalDNIRUC" no existe en tu clase CPlantilla
```

Ya que DisplayMember espera que especifiques una propiedad del objeto CPlanilla mientras que tu estás intentando concatenar tres propiedades, que da como resultado "NombreDelPersonalDNIRUC" y esa propiedad no existe en tu objeto CPlantilla. Para que te des una idea, asigna el siguiente valor  a DisplayMember de la siguiente manera

```
listbxPlanilla.DisplayMember = "NombreDelPersonal" // Verás que ahora si está mostrando los datos pues la propiedad si existe en tu clase
```

Esto se debe a que la propiedad NombreDelPersonal si existe.

Para resolver el problema te recomiendo que a tu clase le agregues una propiedad que ya incluya los datos concatenados que necesitas.

Como referencia puedes leer

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember?view=netframework-4.8

Espero te sea de utilidad